# How can i obtain a 247 white in blender 2.8?

Tags: compositing-nodes, color

I want to obtai a 247 white background.In blender 2.79 to obtain this you should set the RGB (R=0.930,G=0.930,B=0.930 and A=1).In blender 2.80 the result is not the same.I obtain a grey color.

Comment: Stop using 8 bit integer range to express code value positions, and consider how a scene is rendered to display. That’s a deep rabbit hole worth diving into. The rest will all flow from that research.

Answer (score 1):

Read about color transformations [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/color-management-what-is-the-difference-between-display-device-view-transform/134567#134567) first, then ...

- use an emission material and
- set the view transform to *Raw*.

[image: img]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF8wb.png)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason of that is the [color management](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#render). Which have been change in 2.8.

You may want to use the "Standard" view transform instead of the default "Filmic":
[image]