# Blender 2.82 - 2D Grease Pencil Colours seem dimmed in Renders?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, grease-pencil, 2d

So I'm testing out more of Blender's Grease Pencil for animation, but I'm noticing that the colours I draw in the Viewpoint do not render out the exact same, and look darkened.

As a test, I drew a simple face on a scuplted sphere, with just black and white, however the White of the eyes looks darkened when rendered...
[image: Viewport Render looks fine]

[image: Actual render dims colours]

Does anyone have a solution for this? Thank you in advance.

EDIT - Thanks to [Leander](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/30849/leander) for the solution, the issue was using having it set to Filmic colour rather than Standard.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the Filmic default in the [colormanagement](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/color-management-what-is-the-difference-between-display-device-view-transform)? Try switching to *Standard*.

Comment: Ah there we go, that fixed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Please don't add *solved* to the question title. If you have the time, write an answer and accept it for future visitors. How this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour and how to write an answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 3):

Answer - Thanks to [Leander](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/30849/leander) for the advice, the default Filmic colour space in Colour Management had to be set to Standard for the render to come out correctly.

[image: Color Management]

One thing else to check, if you are setting up a Grease Pencil object from scratch and light is having an effect on the color: With the grease pencil object selected, inside *Properties* panel, go to the *Object Data Properties* tab. It's the tab that uses the green squiggle line.

In the tab, you should see your *Layers* expandable menu. Expand it and look below the *Opacity* slider, you'll see a checkbox called **Use Lights**. If you click this off, your grease pencil object will display colors as expected, if you leave it on then you can light the grease pencil objects using a normal light source.