# Saved image is darker than the render

Tags: rendering, image, saving

[image]After toggling every switch I can't seem to figure it out. Basically I have a test render (on the right), I saved it, and then I open it (on the left) and it is several shades darker

I have no idea why.

Comment: Read this thread: [Blender image output gets greyish touch](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/176754/30849). As a follow up, learn about [view transforms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/134495/30849).

Comment: I'm sorry, but the image was not attached to the topic. Can you post them again, please?