# What kind of LOG curve is Filmic Log?

Tags: export, color-management, filmic-blender

I'm not sure why this info is so hard to find but what kind of log is used when you export filmic log?

Like Cineon Film log, Arri Log-C, Slog, or is it some proprietary blender log that Resolve hasn't added to its color space transform options.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Color Management. What is the difference between display device, view transform and sequencer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134495/color-management-what-is-the-difference-between-display-device-view-transform)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best place to learn about it is on the creator's Github:

[GitHub - sobotka/filmic-blender: Film Emulsion-Like Camera Rendering Transforms for Blender](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender)

> This is a simple OpenColorIO configuration for intermediate to advanced imagers using Blender's Cycles raytracing engine, or the Renderman system as included by default.

There is also this ticket which might interest you:
[Filmic LUT for Resolve · Issue #40 · sobotka/filmic-blender · GitHub](https://github.com/sobotka/filmic-blender/issues/40)
Feel free to participate in the discussion there or creating your own "discussion" issue with the developer.